# How to populate FROM field with different Email ID on Case Email option

Tags: email, case

How to populate the FROM field on Email option with different email IDs based on the Case record type.

For example, I would like to show Accounts@email.com for Accounts Case record type, finance@email.com for Finance Case record type. How to use the formula field on below screen to populate with different email Ids.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mention the `Case` object in your formula:

```
IF ($RecordType.Name = 'Account', 
   'Accounts@email.com',
   IF ($RecordType.Name = 'Finance',
      'Finance@email.com',
      ''
   )
)
```

You can use `CASE` function as well:

```
CASE(
  $RecordType.Name, 
  'Account', 'Accounts@email.com', 
  'Finance', 'Finance@email.com',
  ''
)
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you.